# Is it possible for a Microsoft Teams Messaging Extension to know which 1:1 Chat it was invoked from?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

A messaging extension is associated with a Microsoft Teams bot. When invoked, such as for getting search results, it sets up a conversation with the bot it was associated with. That bot is aware of the Teams user X who invoked the messaging extension.

However, is it possible to know the context in which the messaging extension was invoked, for example it was invoked during a 1:1 Chat session with remote user Y?  The use case is to return results in the messaging extension based on the identity of the remote user Y, and not just the identity of X.

Answer (score -1):

I think you could use GetPagedMembersAsync for this - you could get all the members, eliminate the one who actually invoked the message extension, and if there's just one left:

1. then it must have been a 1-1 converstion (note that it might contain your bot as well, so check for that and ignore as well)
2. whoever is left is "user Y"

Comment: Will check it out. At first glance it seemed that method would work when the extension was invoked in a channel..

Comment: You could have a team with 2 members, do not rely on this logic. 

If you're consuming Bot Builder SDK (https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet), you would receive turnContext that will capture the conversation details. (turnContext.Activity.Conversation.ConversationType)

Comment: You can either (a) eliminate that possibility in the app manifest by not allowing the bot to be installed into a Team, only a group/1-1 chat, or (b) yes you could check from turnContext whether it is in a Channel (Team) versus a group chat. In either case though, you'll need to get the members, remove the bot, and remove user X to get whoever is left

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow op never said that he/she didn't want the app in team scope.

I suggest you edit the answer to include the right flow - check for conversation type, if its groupChat, then check if it has only 2 users for the desired outcome.